# can ever the intent received by a BroadcastReceiver be null?

Tags: android, android-intent, nullpointerexception, broadcastreceiver

In other words :

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    final String action = intent.getAction(); // can intent==null here ?
    // could it ever throw a NPE ?
}
```

I need to solve this once and for all so please no ifs and buts. I would check for null but I suspect that it is not needed and therefore it is clumsy and inelegant to check. I had searched in the docs but have not found anything

EDIT : asked at google groups - see [there](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/tCnjmrI4sg0) for some interesting points

Comment: Upvoted. I am getting crash reports from users which suggest that intent can definitely be null under rare circumstances.

Comment: When implementing member onReceive when using BroadcastReceiver, the suggested forms from kotlin, (I  suggests it is from some -ktx library) is ```override fun onReceive(p0: Context?, p1: Intent?)``` which clearly suggests that those variable can be null. 

You should check!

Comment: @RoarGrønmo Kotlin only checks the Java signature which is not annotated, therefore it falls back to the “safer” assumption that it may be null. But it does not mean that it can be null.

Answer (score 10):

`onReceive` in a `BroadcastReceiver` is triggered by an `Intent` with an action that it's registered to. So without Intent being an instance of `Intent` and not null, the `onReceive` method would never get called.

That being said, strange things can happen. I haven't looked over the code that Google wrote around broadcasts, so while in it's correct usage it would never be null, having the check is a good idea, because **it's coming from code you don't control.**

Comment: I've just stumbled upon this exact situation. My app crashed in 4.2.1 when I unmounted the SD card and in logcat there was an NPE within one BroadcastReceiver.onReceive override. I could easily reproduce it. Once I made a null check for the intent argument, the app stopped crashing.

Comment: Could you post your `onReceive` code and the logcat as well? Maybe upload to a pastebin. If you could keep the line numbers in the code that'd be helpful. I'm curious about this.